# JSP form and object

Tags: java, forms, jsp, populate

I want to ask you how to populate form in jsp (form:form or typically html form) with existed java object's attributes. And after changing them, how can I save this property? I googled for long but I cannot find anything about that. Thanks for advance for help.

Comment: use some frameworks like structs or spring mvc.All these have inbuilt capabilities for loading jsps with java objects and saving form data directly to Pojos

Comment: You use [EL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) to populate the form in JSP and retrieve the values from request using the parameter names which are sent to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: Yes, in home Im working on spring mvc application and in this way I understand how to do this. But in work I have different project when I cannot use any framework. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the frameworks you use.

If you use any component based MVC frameworks, the binding between your form, your object can be done. So that your form will be pre-populated with the values available in your object and vice-versa. Example frameworks are JSF, Spring MVC

If you want to do it manually

while generating form in your JSP, you can manually iterate through the java object in JSP and assign value to the form fields using scriptlets 
For example

```
<input type="text" name="name" value='<%=yourObject.getField()%>' />
```

Comment: Yes, the second solution, that was exactly what I needed, thanks :)

Comment: if you found the answer useful, you can accept the answer as its customary in SO. though i can respect your choice.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a regular form you can use the following notation.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="somepage.jsp">
<input type="text" name="name" value='<%=request.getParameter("name")==null?"":request.getParameter("name")'/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

you can access the parameters on the server side by using the same `request.getParameter("name")` call..
I would strongly recommend you to use a framework here like Spring MVC, Struts2 etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks such as struts1,struts2 and more can do the things for you. Basically you need some kind of beans or DTO's for holding jsp-page data.
In struts2 ,its is very simple,dynamic and powerful.Struts2 holds the jsp-page data in its value-stack.

But in jsp using servlet you have to use java-objects on jsp-page inside **scriptlet-tags**.